# Как понять, есть ли локальная сеть с доступными хостами

Tags: qt, ip, wifi

Есть программа на Qt, которая обменивается файлами по локальной сети. Нужно добавить получение списка хостов

```
foreach (const QHostAddress &address, QNetworkInterface::allAddresses()) {
if (address.protocol() == QAbstractSocket::IPv4Protocol && address !=QHostAddress(QHostAddress::LocalHost)) currenthost=address.toString();
}
```

Получение локального адреса осуществляется так. Далее я просто пытаюсь подключится к каждому из 255 сокетов, которые возможно есть в локальной сети путем замены последних цифр локального адреса на числа 1-255 и если соединение срабатывает, я пишу адрес в список

Но если запустить программу с мобильного устройства при мобильном интернете, локальной сети не будет. Как отловить такое событие, без использования нативных проверок на каждой платформе?

Comment: для андроида надо иметь разрешение на доступ к интерфейсу, добавляется в AndroidManifest.xml, для iOS по моему никак

Answer (score 0):

В Qt есть возможность определить, через что произошло подключение к сети http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkconfiguration.html

Если подключены к мобильной сети, там точно локалки нет.